# Elasticsearch Java API Create Index with Mapping fails

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-mapping

I am attempting to create new indices in Elasticsearch 7 leveraging the java api. I am able to create a new index just fine, expect when I try to either create it with a mapping, or try to add the mapping after the fact per the docs:

[add mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html)

[create index with mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html)

this works fine, when I simply create an index

```
public boolean createIndex(RestHighLevelClient client, String indexName) throws IOException {
    CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);

    //no options just straight forward
    CreateIndexResponse response = client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    return response.isAcknowledged();
}
```

however, adding the request.mapping (this example from the webpage) breaks it?

```
request.mapping(
        "{\n" +
        "  \"properties\": {\n" +
        "    \"firstName\": {\n" +
        "      \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}", 
        XContentType.JSON);
```

even if I try to apply the mapping with putMapping after the fact it breaks it as well

```
public boolean createMappingOnIndex(RestHighLevelClient client, String indexName, String mapping) throws IOException {
    PutMappingRequest request = new PutMappingRequest(indexName);

    //instead of using my own, using the example from docs to simplify, still not working
    request.source(
       "{\n" +
       "  \"properties\": {\n" +
       "    \"firstName\": {\n" +
       "      \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
       "    }\n" +
       "  }\n" +
       "}", 
     XContentType.JSON);

    AcknowledgedResponse response = client.indices(). putMapping(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    return response.isAcknowledged();
}
```

errors I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to close the XContentBuilder
     at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.close
caused by: java.io.IOException: Unclosed Object or array found
     at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentGenerator.close(JsonXContentGenerator.java ###)
```

I have tried using the Hashmap implementation instead of the string version, though once it gets into the es bytes it seems to the be the same thing. This is strange because whether I use something like Gson, or just write a a string example escaped or not, the request object does the conversion it needs internally (I think), and then elastic has an issue with the format it created?

I should mention that this is all within a Spring Maven context, and the creation/insertion of indices/documents are done from singleton bean. Though I can't find any indication of that being the culprit here? It works fine when I just create a index without the mapping attached.

Any help is greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: Are you trying to create a mapping type?.If yes then mapping types are deprecated/removed in es 7.

Comment: No not a type, I believe you are correct types were deprecated in version 6. Rather a mapping on an index, see the links to the documentation in the question.

Comment: Ok.Thanks let me set it up locally.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering my own but in case someone else runs into this: All of the above is fine, it was the way my RestHighLevelClient was being returned from Spring bean that was the issue.

Comment: hi, i'm meeting these exception when using RestHighLevelClient and Spring, too. Can you share how the way you fix it?